# C# - Overriding only part of the function

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class, called `Party` and function in it, which is called `OnMemberDeath()`. I've created new class called `PlayerParty` which inherits from `Party` and now I need to add only two but very important lines to the `OnMemberDeath( )` function *( Example below )*. Is it possible to override only part of the method?

## What I'm trying to achieve

Party class is responsible for detecting turn-based combat stuff. Also, every Party has members ( entities ) and SelectionOrb ( little circle below them ). When member of a party dies, new member has to be selected. Through the member selection process the SelectionOrb has to receive new parent ( AdjustWorldObject() ) as well as the reference to selected member has to be assigned ( for battle stuff ). If none alive members are left, we need to set parent to `null` so that SelectionOrb is not deleted together with the Member object.
In PlayerParty class there's new object, which is CombatUI and it is acting basicly the same as SelectionOrb( has to receive new parent after current's death ). Hopefully this is clear enough.

```
    /** in Party class **/
protected void OnMemberDeath( )
{
    if( aliveCount > 1 )
    {
        AdjustWorldObject( );
        aliveCount--;
    }

    else
    {
        ResetWorldObject( );

        if( OnPartyDeath != null ) OnPartyDeath( ); // Event
        else print( "Party died but event had no subscriptions!" );
    }
}

    /** in PlayerParty class **/
new void OnMemberDeath( )
{
    if( aliveCount > 1 )
    {
        AdjustWorldObject( );
        AdjustCombatUI( ); // The first line I want to add
    }

    else
    {
        ResetWorldObject( );
        ResetCombatUI( ); // The second line I want to add

        if( OnPartyDeath != null ) OnPartyDeath( ); // Event
        else print( "Party died but event had no subscriptions!" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope you can't do that without rewriting the IL.

Comment: So I think I'll have to create some additional functions, like `DoSomethingIfAlive( )` and `DoSomethingIfNot( )` and override those instead ?

Comment: @Sw3das yeap, you can do it this way

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain a bit better in a second ( wait for post edit )

Comment: @MrsEd Done the editing!

Comment: Are `AdjustWorldObject` and `ResetWorldObject` called only from this function?

Comment: @MrsEd it's an event :)

Comment: @IvanStoev yes, they are

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to override only part of the method ?

No, it's not possible. You need to extract the parts of the function that needs to be overridden into a new `virtual` methods.

For instance, if your `AdjustWorldObject` and `ResetWorldObject` are called only from this method, you can make them virtual and override when needed like this

```
class Party
{
    protected void OnMemberDeath( )
    {
        if(aliveCount > 1)
        {
            AdjustWorldObject();
            aliveCount--;
        }
        else
        {
            ResetWorldObject();
            if(OnPartyDeath != null) OnPartyDeath(); // Event
            else print( "Party died but event had no subscriptions!" );
        }
    }
    protected virtual void AdjustWorldObject()
    {
        // ...
    }
    protected virtual void ResetWorldObject()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class PlayerParty : Party
{
    protected override void AdjustWorldObject()
    {
        base.AdjustWorldObject();
        AdjustCombatUI();
    }
    protected override void ResetWorldObject()
    {
        base.ResetWorldObject();
        ResetCombatUI();
    }
}
```

If they are not, you can create similar dedicated virtual methods.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though your override method doesn't fit my needs as AdjustCombatUI() has to be called only if aliveCount > 1... But I'll take it just as pure example and not full code :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Sw3das But as you may see, `AdjustWorldObject()` virtual method is called from the base class only when `aliveCount > 1`, so the same will be with your `AdjustCombatUI`, no?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you got me :D